# Way to test a hypothesis that mean of A is N times greater than mean of B?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, ratio

I designed an experiment where there are two treatments: A and B.
Each subject does both A and B with a randomized order, so it's a within-subject design.

For example, the data would look as follows:

| subject | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 351 | 699 |
| 2 | 322 | 742 |
| 3 | 294 | 452 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 100 | 257 | 601 |

Traditionally, people would test hypothesis whether mean of A is significantly greater than mean of B.  (H0: diff = 0, H1: diff > 0)

What I want to do is test whether mean of A is significantly 2 times greater than mean of B.
Is there a statistical method to show this? Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. "mean of A is significantly 2 times greater than mean of" ... your use of the word significantly implies you are taking about the alternative there. Please state a clear null and alternative hypothesis (about populations). 2. Are you envisioning the entire distribution being scaled ('values tend to double on average')? 3. What are you measuring?

Comment: I suspect you already know how to do this: for each subject compute $X=A-2B.$  Test the hypothesis $H_0:E[X]\le 0.$

Comment: Because your A-values are smaller then B-values, I suspect you want to look at $2A - B.$

Comment: Thank you all! All your comments here are very helpful. I guess I can define the random variable as X = 2A - B as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A definitive answer would require all of the data (so that one could check for normality) or additional information about the distributions from which the data were chosen.

Assuming that the data are approximately normal and that A and B are paired,
a 1-sample t test  on the differences $D = 2A- B$
can do what you want.

From the sizes of your values, I suspect you intended to ask of the mean of twice A exceeds the mean of B. Here are fictitious data somewhat similar to yours, sampled in R.

```
set.seed(2021)
a = rnorm(100, 300, 50)
b = rnorm(100, 550, 70)
d = 2*a - b

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-278.10  -49.05   27.26   32.66  119.09  344.63
```

In the boxplot below, a red 'X' shows the location of $D.$ (It is not unusual for
normal samples of size 100 to show a few 'outliers'.)

```
boxplot(d, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
 points(32.66, 1, pch="X", col="red")
```

[image]

For my fictitious data, $H_0: \mu_D = 0$ is rejected in
favor of $H_a: \mu_D > 0,$ with P-value below 1%.

```
t.test(d, alt="gr")

        One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = 2.4774, df = 99, p-value = 0.007464
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 10.77135      Inf
```

sample estimates:
mean of x
32.6623

*Note:* In R, alternative syntax for essentially the same test is `t.test(2*a, b, pair=T, alt="gr")`.

Comment: The values in the question appear to be paired on subject.

Comment: Right. Fixed it. Thanks to you and @whuber

Comment: Isn't the null technically $\mu_d \le 0$?

Comment: Optional, depending on whose text you look at. In any case $\mu_D = 0$ determines the null distribution. But in your formulation, $H_0$ and $H_a$ together account for the whole real line, which some authors prefer.